# Does every point of a Riemannian manifold have a normal neighborhood?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

According to Lee's *Introduction to Riemannian manifolds*, a neighborhood $U$ of $p\in(M,g)$ that is the diffeomorphic image of a star-shaped neighborhood of $0\in T_p M$ under the restricted exponential map $\exp_p$ is called a ***normal neighborhood of $p$***.

**Question 1:** What is meant by a star-shaped neighborhood of $0\in T_p M$?

I know exactly what a star-shaped set is like, but I have a hard time grasping the meaning of a star-shaped neighborhood of $0$. Is it an open neighborhood $W$ of $0$ that is star-shaped with respect to some point (possibly distinct from $0$) in $W$? Or is it an open neighborhood of $0$ that is star-shaped w.r.t. $0$?

**Question 2:** Does each $p\in M$ have a normal neighborhood?

With the help of the inverse function theorem, it is guaranteed that there exist a neighborhood $V$ of $0\in T_p M$ and a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that $\exp_p$ maps $V$ diffeomorphically onto $U$, which is pretty close to the definition of a normal neighborhood. However, to answer Question 2, one must be able to show that $V$ contains a star-shaped neighborhood of $0$. Let us forget about Question 1 and assume for simplicity that a star-shaped neighborhood of $0$ is an open neighborhood of $0$ that is star-shaped w.r.t. $0$. Does anyone know how to show that $V$ contains such neighborhood?

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I understand, one has to require that the neighborhood is star shaped with respect to $0$. The answer to Question 2 then clearly is yes, since any ball is star shaped around its center.

Comment: @AndreasCap Thank you, but in an abstract manifold, how can we talk about a "ball"?

Comment: The ball is in the tangent space $T_pM$, which is a vector space endowed with an inner product. So you take a sufficiently small ball there and consider its image under $exp_p$.

Comment: It may be worth noting that a ball in this setting need not be (geodesically) convex: On a round unit sphere, a ball of radius greater than $\pi/2$ (i.e., containing a closed hemisphere) but not the whole sphere fails to be convex because "it's shorter to go around the other hemisphere." In the extreme case of radius $\pi$, the ball is not star-shaped with respect to any point _except_ the center.